# issue with multiplying sequences in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone tell me why my code is returning the error (in the Python IDLE)?:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' ".

here is the code that's been causing the errors:

```
def main():
    varone = input("Enter total number of episodes:  ")
    vartwo = input("enter approx. time of each episode (in minutes):  ")
    varthree = varone * vartwo
    print(varthree)
    print("minutes")
main()
```

Comment: It looks like it'll throw even more errors than that, your indentation is very wrong and python is white-space dependent. Please update your question with the correct spacing.

Comment: question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends on whether you are using python 2.x or 3.x

in 3.x input always gives you a string, so a quick fix is:

```
varthree = int(varone) * int(vartwo)
```

Comment: python 2.x will evaluate the text entered, which could be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns strings... Convert to integers:

```
varthree = int(varone) * int(vartwo)
```